# Application main for JAX-RS webservice

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jax-ws

I am currently implementing my first JAX-RS based REST service and during my research on JAX-RS I found two version how to implement the main 'entry point' of the application. One option is to implement a class that starts a server in its main method:

```
public class Spozz {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //String webappDirLocation = "src/main/webapp/";
        int port = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("port", "8087"));
        Server server = new Server(port);

        ProtectionDomain domain = Spozz.class
                .getProtectionDomain();
        URL location = domain.getCodeSource().getLocation();

        WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
        webapp.setContextPath("/");
        webapp.setDescriptor(location.toExternalForm() + "/WEB-INF/web.xml");
        webapp.setResourceBase(location.toExternalForm());
        webapp.setServer(server);
        webapp.setWar(location.toExternalForm());

        webapp.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

        // (Optional) Set the directory the war will extract to.
        // If not set, java.io.tmpdir will be used, which can cause problems
        // if the temp directory gets cleaned periodically.
        // Your build scripts should remove this directory between deployments
        webapp.setTempDirectory(new File(location.toExternalForm()));

        server.setHandler(webapp);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

The other one to extend the `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` class.

```
@ApplicationPath("/services")
public class Spozz extends Application {
    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();
    private Set<Class<?>> empty = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

    public Spozz() {
        singletons.add(new UserResource());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        return empty;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        return singletons;
    }
}
```

However, I have seen both version in many different examples, but it was never explained why  this version was chosen and what the benefits are. I personally would stick with the second one, but I do not really have a reason for that. So my questions are:

1. What are the differences of this options?
2. Which one is preferable when using JAX-RS 2.0?
3. Is it important if I would like to add servlets to the service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are the differences of this options?

Option #1 is really only meant as a quick start. There are many attributes to a web container that you'd want to tweak in a production environment, such as thread pools / number of threads / connectors / etc. I'm unsure about which embedded container your code relates to, but web container configuration is best left to config files and not code in production.

> Which one is preferable when using JAX-RS 2.0?

If you're prototyping, use #1. For production use #2. For an entry point into a jersey application, extending the `Application` class is the way to go. So it is not really a matter of choice.

> Is it important if I would like to add servlets to the service?

I'm not sure what that means. You'd like to add servlets at a later point in time ? It does not matter if you're using an embedded container or a standalone container. Servlets are servlets. They'll serve requests when they are in a container.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Really helped me. But if I should use #1 for prototyping and #2 for production, how could I switch between them without altering my code every time?

Comment: They are independent of each other. You have a war file already, so use that to deploy to a container. You can for example use a [CI like Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) to automatically deploy a war when your code changes. The prototype code need not change since it does not depend on the other method.